# Get value from table as a reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, ref

In c++ it`s possible to do it by reference (&) or pointer (*). In C# there is "ref". How to get value from table and change it by reference to it?

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] t=new int[3]{1,2,3};
            int a=t[0]; //ref int a=t[0];
            a+=10;
            System.Console.WriteLine("a={0}", a);   //11
            System.Console.WriteLine("t[0]={0}", t[0]); //1
        }
    }
}
```

E.g. in c++

```
int &a=tab[0];
```

Comment: A very important point here is that *C# is not C++*. There's no rule that says that just because it exists in C++ then it must exist in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has only become feasible in C# 7, using *ref locals*:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] t = {1, 2, 3};
        ref int a = ref t[0];
        a += 10;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"a={a}");       // 11
        System.Console.WriteLine($"t[0]={t[0]}"); // 11
    }
}
```

This is the important line:

```
ref int a = ref t[0];
```

C# 7 also supports *ref returns*. I would advise using both features sparingly - while they can certainly be useful, they will be unfamiliar to many C# developers, and I can see them causing significant confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It can be with pointer in Unsafe mode

```
unsafe
{
      int[] t = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
      fixed (int* lastPointOfArray = &t[2])
      {
          *lastPointOfArray = 6;
          Console.WriteLine("last item of array {0}", t[2]); // =>> last item of array 6
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No. It's not possible for a value type like int. However, it is standard for reference types.

For instance:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty {get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var t=new MyClass[3]{new MyClass {MyProperty=1},new MyClass {MyProperty=2},new MyClass {MyProperty=3}};
    var a=t[0]; //ref int a=t[0];
    a.MyProperty+= 10;
    System.Console.WriteLine("a={0}", a.MyProperty);   //11
    System.Console.WriteLine("t[0]={0}", t[0].MyProperty); //11
}
```

gives the expected result.

**Edit**: Apparently I'm behind. As Jon Skeet points out it's possible in C# 7.0.